# Strange ternary condition in JavaScript or Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I am working on a code where I found this code in the view. As far as I know, ternary condition contains one "?" and then 2 set of instructions separated by a colon ":". I cannot understand how this ternary operator is working - as it has 3 question marks and only 1 colon.

**Ternary Operator syntax:**

```
var result = condition? if true do this : if false do this;
```

**Custom code written in Angular:**

```
<p>{{ myModal?.subTotal!=null ? '$'+myModal?.subTotal : '' }}</p>
```

Can someone explain how this ternary condition is written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this part - `myModal?.subTotal != null`

If `myModal` is `undefined or null`, return `false`. Else access it's `subTotal` property and if it is not `null` return `true`, else `false`.

This is the same as `myModal && myModal.subTotal != null`

For more you can see [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths).

Answer (score 1):

The first and last question marks are not the ternary operator in this case.

```
myModal?.subTotal!=null ? '$'+myModal?.subTotal : ''
(condition            ) ? (if                 ) : (else)
```

See [The safe navigation operator (`?.`) and null property paths](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) for details.

> The Angular safe navigation operator (`?.`) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.